# Does anyone know how to create a multi-select drop down in excel based on another multi-select drop down?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, multi-select, vba

I am hoping someone can help me (I have a very tight turn around time (48 hours). I have a multi-select drop-down in one of my columns in excel. The user can select and de-select values from a list of 12 values (They usually select no more than 2 at a time). What I want is then based on the values selected in that column, that it populates another multi-select drop down in a second column.

For example(not real example but I can't share values in real example):

**Column A:** Fruit, Vegetables, Meat, Dairy 
(They can select any of the above, and are stored as (Fruit, Vegetables) in cell. They can come back and say they want to deselect Fruit and add Meat then it would be stored as (Vegetables, Meat).

**Column B:** Fruit options are (F1, F2, F3) Vegetables (V1, V2, V3) Meat (M1, M2, M3) and Dairy (D1, D2, D3) etc.

Data validation only works if an individual selects one option for Column A. What I want to work is that it recognizes there are 2 or more values in column A and then display the corresponding values in Column B in a drop-down for user to select that is also multi-select and also allows for edits.

Why am I doing this? I need to create a dashboard to display the number of times values in column A are selected and number of times values in column B are selected, and also which ones were not selected, having them all in one column I figured was easier rather than having a separate column for each value where user inputs an 'x' if applicable.

I am open to better ways to do this.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

My code Thus far:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rngDV As Range
Dim oldVal As String
Dim newVal As String
Dim strVal As String
Dim i As Long
Dim lCount As Long
Dim Ar As Variant
On Error Resume Next
Dim lType As Long
If Target.Count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler
lType = Target.Validation.Type
If lType = 3 Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
newVal = Target.Value
Application.Undo
oldVal = Target.Value
Target.Value = newVal
If Target.Column = 7 Or Target.Column = 8 Or Target.Column = 12 Or         Target.Column = 13 Then
If oldVal = "" Then
'do nothing
Else
If newVal = "" Then
'do nothing
Else
On Error Resume Next
Ar = Split(oldVal, ", ")
strVal = ""
For i = LBound(Ar) To UBound(Ar)
Debug.Print strVal
Debug.Print CStr(Ar(i))
If newVal = CStr(Ar(i)) Then
'do not include this item
strVal = strVal
lCount = 1
Else
strVal = strVal & CStr(Ar(i)) & ", "
End If
Next i
If lCount > 0 Then
Target.Value = Left(strVal, Len(strVal) - 2)
Else
Target.Value = strVal & newVal
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
exitHandler:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Quick search gave me this: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/09/30/dependent-cascading-dropdown-lists-excel/

Comment: Yes that works perfect with a single-select drop-down but I can't figure out how to make that work with multi-select drop-downs :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it involves a bit of arduous coding but you can set validation in specific cells based on other cell values as follows (they are currently hard-coded)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Call FillCombo(Target)
End Sub

Private Function FillCombo(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo ExitFunction
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Function

    Dim ComboList As String, CLUpdate As Boolean: CLUpdate = False
    Dim CLAll As String: CLAll = "Apples,Pears,Oranges"
    Dim CLApp As String: CLApp = "Granny Smith,Pink Lady"
    Dim CLPea As String: CLPea = "Bartlett,Comice"
    Dim CLOra As String: CLOra = "Satsuma,Tangerine,Blood"

    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A2:A4"), "Apples") > 0 _
        Then ComboList = ListJoin(ComboList, CLApp)
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A2:A4"), "Pears") > 0 _
        Then ComboList = ListJoin(ComboList, CLPea)
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A2:A4"), "Oranges") > 0 _
        Then ComboList = ListJoin(ComboList, CLOra)

    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("A2:A4")) Is Nothing Then
        Call UpdateCombo(Target, CLAll)
    End If
    Call UpdateCombo(Range("A6"), ComboList)

ExitFunction:
End Function

Private Function UpdateCombo(ByVal Target As Range, ComboList As String)
    With Target.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:=ComboList
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
    If InStr(ComboList, Target.Value) = 0 Then Target.Value = ""
End Function

Private Function ListJoin(Str1 As String, Str2 As String) As String
    If Str2 = "" Then ListJoin = Str1
    If Str1 = "" And ListJoin = "" Then ListJoin = Str2
    If ListJoin = "" Then ListJoin = Str1 & "," & Str2
End Function
```

Comment: Hmmm I like how this functions but I somehow need to join it to my existing code. (which I have shared above). The problem with the above code is it looks for values in a range of 3 cells (A2:A4) .... For my purposes I would need it to look for multiple values separated by a " ," in one cell. So it would need to see if A2 is greater than one, and if so then display combo list in B2, and so on for each row until A500 and B 500. Does that make sense? I know a bit of VBA but this has stumped me. Thank you though! :)